# Aggregating table to json combined with references to other tables

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, aggregation

Table A:

| id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 |

Table B:

| id | status | a_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 5 | 2 |

```
Table A (
id int,
status int);

Table B(
id int,
status int,
a_id int foreignt key reference A
);
```

How to make query that return such output, when I seek status in (1,3)?

| id | status | arrayjson |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | [{id=1,status=1,a_id=1},{id=2,status=3,a_id=1}] |

If I seek status in ( 3 ), it should return:

| id | status | arrayjson |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | [{id=2,status=3,a_id=1}] |

If I seek status in ( 4 ), it should return:

| id | status | arrayjson |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 4 | [] |

If I seek status in ( 5 ) it should return:

| id | status | arrayjson |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 4 | [{id=2,status=4,a_id=2}] |

Comment: You examples suggests that the `status` is selected from the table `b`. The case for `status = 4` is inconsistentas here seems that the status is taken from the table `a` - I'd expect here no rows or all rows from `a` with empty array as output - pls clarify.

Comment: the statuses should be taken from both tables - this is main requirement

Comment: You have a *parent - child* tables where the *child* is *optional*. You'll have to carefully describe the join condition between the tables in case you consider the *state* from both tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally find the best solution

```
select a.id     as id,
       a.status as status,
       t.bibi   as bibi
from a a

         left join (
    select t.b_a_id                 as b_a_id,
           JSON_AGG(ROW_TO_JSON(t)) as bibi
    from (
             select b.id     as b_id,
                    b.a_id   as b_a_id,
                    b.status as b_status
             from b b
             where b.status in (....)
         ) t
    group by t.b_a_id
) ap on ap.b_a_id = a.id
where (a.status in (...) OR ap.b_a_id is not null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your set of seek status values, you can use:

- [`GENERATE_SERIES`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html), to generate your possible seek_status values
- [`JSON_BUILD_OBJECT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html), to build your json beginning from your B table
- [`JSON_AGG`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html), to aggregate your json
- `WHERE v.seek_status IN (1,3)`, to change the seek_status you need
- `ORDER BY A.status DESC LIMIT 1`, to get the highest status possible among all output records

```
SELECT A.*,
       CASE WHEN MAX(B.status) IS NOT NULL
            THEN JSON_AGG(JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('id'    , B.id,
                                            'status', B.status,
                                            'a_id'  , B.a_id   ))
            ELSE '[]' END AS arrayjson
FROM      GENERATE_SERIES(1,5) v(seek_status)
LEFT JOIN B ON v.seek_status = B.status
LEFT JOIN A ON v.seek_status >= A.status
WHERE v.seek_status IN (1,3)
GROUP BY A.id, A.status, B.status
ORDER BY A.status DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jagekJAMV8YnHQvbXhBiDA/2).

Comment: this answer is wrong  - this query does not rerurn all rows with 1 or 3 status

Comment: Try the updated one.

Comment: it works but its too hard for undnderstanding. There are some ways to do it more easy

Comment: This is the most generalized way to carry out this task. I've linked the documentation for you to read, in case you could not understand it.

Comment: this task is easy to do by this way

Answer (score 0):

This is you basic query with the filter on status from table `B` (example for status 1,3)

```
select 
a.id, a.status, b.id b_id, b.status b_status
from a
join b
on a.id = b.a_id
where b.status in (1,3)

id|status|b_id|b_status|
--+------+----+--------+
 1|     1|   2|       3|
 1|     1|   1|       1|
```

Now you need only to group on the first two columns and aggregate the JSON array.

[json_agg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html)  and [json_build_object](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) are the solution

```
with tab as (
select 
a.id, a.status, b.id b_id, b.status b_status
from a
join b
on a.id = b.a_id
where b.status in (1,3)
)
select tab.id, tab.status,
json_agg(
 json_build_object('id', tab.b_id, 'status', tab.b_status,'a_id',tab.id) 
 ORDER BY b_id) as arrayjson
from tab
group by 1,2
order by 1,2

id|status|arrayjson                                                                   |
--+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 1|     1|[{"id" : 1, "status" : 1, "a_id" : 1}, {"id" : 2, "status" : 3, "a_id" : 1}]|
```